# How to bring a working drive back online?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, zfs

I am using Proxmox with ZFS. In an attempt to regularize the drive names, I offlined and detached a working drive in my vdev mirror-0, however I cannot bring the said drive back up

```
root@r740xd:~# zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                           ONLINE       0     0     0
      scsi-364cd98f06a11110024d430ebb1af8034-part3  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-3                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdh                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-4                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdi                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
```

---

```
zpool online rpool /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-364cd98f06a11110024d42f1e5d9525c
```

I have tried the above command but with no luck, ZFS says no such device in pool, could you please assist me

Answer (score 1):

It looks like by running `zpool detach`, you broke a mirror made of these two devices:

- `/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-364cd98f06a11110024d430ebb1af8034-part3`
- `/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-364cd98f06a11110024d42f1e5d9525c`

All you have to do to bring back the mirror is run this command:

```
zpool attach rpool scsi-364cd98f06a11110024d430ebb1af8034-part3 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-364cd98f06a11110024d42f1e5d9525c
```

---

Mirrors devices are removed with `zpool detach` and added back with `zpool attach`.

Devices are taken out of service temporarily with `zpool offline` and brought back with `zpool online`.

I think you were mixing up the concept of `detach/attach` with `offline/online`.

(There is yet another concept of `zpool remove`, which can remove a vdev and reduce the size of your pool, since [ZFS on Linux 0.8.0](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/releases/tag/zfs-0.8.0).)

Comment: thanks for the reply, however I get the following error

cannot resolve path '/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-364cd98f06a11110024d42f1e5d9525c

not sure why is that

Comment: @NarendraRajcoomar: Are you sure that the detached disk's path is that?  Try listing the paths with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/` to make sure.